# remove empty div in jquery if no class or id attached

Tags: jquery, magento, css-selectors

Hi I have an empty div in my code well magento's and i want to remove it via jquery and tried:

```
$('.col-main > div:empty').remove();
$('div:not([class])'.remove();
$('div[class!=""]').remove();
```

also tried:

```
$('.col-main > div[class!=""]').remove();
$('.col-main > div:not([class])'.remove();
$('.col-main > div[class!="clr"]').remove(); - im guessing here
```

tha last two removed all my divs on the page, but none of them work. I want to keep all divs which are empty which have a class or id attached e.g. clr's.

Comment: Could you show the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read the jQuery spec in details then you can understand it better :)

`:not()` is to exclude an element from the list of elements e.g. $('div:not(.hide)') will select all divs that do not have a .hide class.

`:empty` is when the `html`, or `text` has nothing in it.

anyways.

```
$('div').each(function (i,n){
    if(!$(n).attr('class') || !$(n).attr('id')){
        // neither id or class exist
    }else{
        // id or class exists
    }
})
```

check this link for an example 
http://jsfiddle.net/jz3zT/

Comment: You should really be checking `!$(n).attr('class') && !$(n).attr('id')` instead to make sure that the node doesn't have a class and doesn't have an id. Otherwise if the node doesn't have a class it will execute as though it also doesn't have an id. I assume this was a typo though.

Comment: ermmm well i assumed they can know the difference between `&&` and `||` operators but +1 for the thinking :)

Comment: Hum i had a feeling this would work but it didn't, here is my url: http://www.getbranded.co/magento/index.php/ its just an empty <div></div> which my wc3 validator hates and its only on the index. I also tried: $('div').each(function (i,n){
  if((!$(n).attr('class')) && (!$(n).attr('id'))){
   // neither id or class exist
   remove();
  } else {
   // id or class exists
  }
 }); - sorry dunno how to format it, bah not a great day today :S

Comment: I did thanks but that doesn't work either, bit irritating this.

Comment: it does after 2.5 seconds you will see they both get deleted/removed

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do it either, it hides all the divs on load :( - its strange as the one you linked me too works.

Comment: are this divs created dynamically ? if so they probably are created after you removed them :)

Comment: copy the code from the link go to your browser on console tab there is a place where you can enter js code on the firebug so if it works there it means some other js is creating it, if it doesn't work then its because it keeps getting created at an interval

Comment: @val thanks for that i did that and i get this error: TypeError: $("div:empty:not([class]):not([id])") is null

Comment: hahhaha ok http://jsfiddle.net/jz3zT/ copy everything in the JS box and do it again

Comment: @val - Firebug's log limit has been reached. 0 entries not shown.  Preferences  
>>> function good(){ $('div').each(function (i,n){ ... class exists } }); } setTimeout(good,2500);
90
$("div") is null
[Break On This Error] <ul class="level1">

Comment: `$('div').each(function (i,n){ if(!$(n).attr('class') && !$(n).attr('id')){  $(n).remove();  }});` please use this code I don't know what you have used. on the console where you can insert javascript, i mean the box where it says, `run`,`clear`,`copy` below it so on firebug click console. then next to it is a button with multiple line `show command line` if you see `>>>` in blue on the right there is a red button then it will show the box

Comment: i used the code on that site, just tried yours and it spits this out: Firebug's log limit has been reached. 0 entries not shown.  Preferences  
>>> $('div').each(function (i,n){ if(!$(n).attr('class') && !$(n).attr('id')){ $(n).remove(); }});
TypeError: $("div") is null

Comment: try to replace all `$` with `jQuery` or  add `$ = jQuery;` above the code i gave you i tried it on your website it removes some stuff . also on the if statement add this `&& !$(n).html()` right after `attr('id')`

Comment: `$ = jQuery;
$('div').each(function (i,n){ if(!$(n).attr('class') && !$(n).attr('id') &&!$(n).html()){ $(n).remove(); }});`

Comment: @val thanks val, but still doesn't remove the div in question: 'line 239 column 1 - Warning: trimming empty <div>' - im using the html validator, after running your code in firebug this is the output: $(root).identify is not a function
[Break On This Error] var oldId = root.id, id = $(root).identify();
prototype.js (line 2842)
$(root).identify is not a function
[Break On This Error] var oldId = root.id, id = $(root).identify();

Comment: pls tell me which div(s) you need to remove? e.g. if its under the cart,or facebook link or under view as grid give me an indication where it is. so that you know. the div you want to remove should be empty `<div></div>` no spaces or tabs or new line spaces, must not have an id, and must not have a class with that script above

Comment: @val its here in the source: <div id="content">
    
        <div class="leftfloat" id="col2">
        
        <div class="main-container col2-right-layout">
            <div class="main">
                                <div class="col-main">
                                        <div class="std"><div>
'<div></div>' <-- (thats it)

Comment: ok that works for me mate, its removed, use the `style="background:red; height: 16px; width:16;display:block;"` on that div then run the script so you can visually see it go away. btw you dont need to remove it you know :) it does no harm

Comment: hi Val yea your right but won't validate to W3C which is annoying because of that issue, i enabled template debugging in magento in the hope i could find the file but no luck yet :( bah bloody headache.

Comment: but validate W3C only validates your source code. And your javascript removes it after the whole source code is successfully loaded and ignore any javascript removed elements. so they only get a plain text of your html and check for tags that are closed properly and in right order. `<div><p></div></p>` is wrong etc they can't check everything a website does. if that helps you understand how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS selector question really, there is no need to specify the framework used nor start writing loops nor use `.each`.

The following finds empty DIVs without a class name or ID.

```
div:empty:not([class]):not([id])
```

It's that simple.

Comment: how does that exactly remove the element?

Comment: @Val - The above is only the selector, which is the essence of the question. To perform a remove it's `$('div:empty:not([class]):not([id])').remove()` in jQuery or `$$('div:empty:not([class]):not([id])').invoke('remove')` in Prototype (which comes with Magento) or Mootools. In all cases the important part is a correct selector and in this case is the part the OP was confused on.

Comment: that makes sense :) I could be wrong here but doesn't :not exclude an element from the list? you are essentially saying select divs,that are empty, exclude[class] exclude[id]

Comment: @Val - That is the intention. When terms in a selector are touching (no space) then it acts like an AND. When separated by a comma it is an OR. We only want to match divs that are empty AND don't have a class attribute AND don't have an id attribute.

Comment: thats kinda clever i will check this out :)

Comment: clockworkgeek i tried $('div:empty:not([class]):not([id])').remove(); also tried $('.col-main > div:empty:not([class]):not([id]).remove(); but it won't work

Comment: @user641560 - What doesn't work? If you have firebug or chrome's developer tools type `$('div:empty:not([class]):not([id])')` into the console and see if an error occurs, it should show you a list of the elements you are interested in.

Comment: Clockworkgeek, it doesn't remove the <div></div>, i have firebug, no errors show

Answer (score 0):

You may have to loop through them with `each` and check whether `.attr('class')` and `.attr('id')` are set.